# Data grid row filter return less than

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, rowfilter

when i run this to filter my xml file it returns all rows even those higher than the given amount.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();



ds.ReadXml("Database.xml");

string filter = "";
filter = "Dayvisited <= '20'";

DataView dv = new DataView(ds.Tables[0]);
dv.RowFilter = filter;
dataGridView2.DataSource = dv;
dataGridView2.Columns[4].Visible = false;
```

this is my xml

```
<root>
  <place>
    <Name />
    <Location />
    <Info />
    <Dayvisited />
    <userdata />
  </place>
  <place>
    <Name>home</Name>
    <Location>x-292 z 277</Location>
    <Info>home</Info>
    <Dayvisited>100</Dayvisited>
    <userdata>u</userdata>
  </place>
  <place>
    <Name>base</Name>
    <Location>x868 z986</Location>
    <Info>stuff</Info>
    <Dayvisited>20</Dayvisited>
    <userdata>u</userdata>
  </place>
  <place>
    <Name>town</Name>
    <Location>x 990 z-2485</Location>
    <Info>gas station</Info>
    <Dayvisited>12</Dayvisited>
    <userdata>u</userdata>
  </place>
  <place>
    <Name>crossing</Name>
    <Location>x 90 z-2998</Location>
    <Info>working stiff</Info>
    <Dayvisited>11</Dayvisited>
    <userdata>u</userdata>
  </place>
  <place>
    <Name>home</Name>
    <Location>x-280 z 277</Location>
    <Info>home and more stuff</Info>
    <Dayvisited>125</Dayvisited>
    <userdata>u</userdata>
  </place>
</root>
```

how can i make it return only those with Dayvisited less than 20 to the data grid?. i thought using textbox for the value was confusing something so i changed it to just use 20 and it still does it and i dont know why.

how i add user input to the file

```
try
{

DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
dr["Name"] = Nametb.Text;
dr["Location"] = Locationtb.Text;
dr["Info"] = Infotb.Text;
dr["Dayvisited"] = dayvisitcb.Text;
dr["userdata"] = "u";
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(dr);
ds.WriteXml("Database.xml");

}
catch (Exception)
{
throw;
}
```

Comment: have you tried `"Dayvisited <= 20"` ?

Comment: yes it says this,"Cannot perform '<=' operation on System.String and System.Int32."

Comment: Can you add the code that reads the data into the `DataSet`? It seems that you store the value of `DayVisited` as a string. This leads to "100" being less than "20" in alphabetical order. That's why all the records are shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that you read the value of `DayVisited` as a string. So a comparison of `"100" < "20"` turns out to be true in a string comparison. This leads to the row being included into the result.

In order to compare the value correctly, you have to convert it to an integer before:

```
filter = "Convert(Dayvisited, System.Int32) <= 20"
```

However, as your XML file contains a row without data for `DayVisited` at the beginning, you have to prepare for invalid data. Thus you have to check the length of the string before to exclude the invalid row:

```
filter = "IIF(LEN(DayVisited) = 0, FALSE, Convert(Dayvisited, System.Int32) <= 20)"
```

If you want to include the empty row in the result, change the `FALSE` to `TRUE`.

Comment: it still sees numbers like 10,18,15,101,10240 as below 2

Comment: How to you create the datatable? Do you read it from a database or do you set it up manually? Looks like it is still doing a string comparison.

Comment: can you explain your question more please ?

Comment: Where does `ds` come from? Can you add the code that creates `ds` to your question?

Comment: @Nathanials-c I've updated my answer so that it should filter your rows correctly. You have to convert the value to an integer before comparing.